# Injective endomorphism and determinant

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove this:

Let $R$ be a ring, and $A \in M_n(R)$.  Write $L_A$ for the linear map $L_A : R^n \to R^n$ determined by left multiplication by $A$.  Shows that if $L_A$ is injective, then $\det(A)$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/161523/469000

Comment: You meant a commutative ring. The adjugate matrix should help.

Comment: Particular case (for $m=n$) of part **b)** of https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h124137 .

Comment: Thanks!  Works for me.